# Match whole phrase except first 2 chars in regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I remove everything after the 2 first chars of every line in Notepad++?

From

```
AC  ABL ASSIS BRASIL    ASSIS BRASIL    68
AC  ACAV    ACARAUA-BR 364  TARAUACA    68
AC  ACLD    ACRELANDIA  ACRELANDIA  68
AC  ASBR    ASSIS BRASIL    CRUZEIRO DO SUL 68
```

to

```
AC
AC
AC
```

I am unable to match the whole word execept the first 2 chars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search for

```
^(..).*
```

and replace all with `\1`.

If Notepad handles lookaround assertions sensibly, the following might be faster: Search for

```
(?<=^..).*
```

and replace with nothing.

Comment: Posted almost at the same time! xD Also, yup, notepad++ does support lookarounds, so the second works as well. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can search for:

```
^(.{2}).*
```

And replace all with `\1`.  This will match and capture any two characters at the beginning of each line.